# I am struggling to make my Android item view responsive to different size screens

Tags: android, dynamic, android-constraintlayout

ok so I have been battling with the design side of android for some time. I am not sure if this belongs here or in code review as I am also asking for advice, whilst there are no major issues / bugs with the layout, it isn't producing the desired results I am getting much better at Kotlin and more back end coding but getting my visual layout to have the desired results doesn't appear to be working for me.

SO I have a item.xml file for recycler view items. I have tried using match parent on width for side by side views, odp, wrap content, match constraints which zeroes out the widths. And this is how much I am struggling I am even wondering if I am explaining myself properly

advice;

small screen v large screen - I see lots of conflicting statements about some saying you should not just make things bigger on a bigger screen, when should it be and when shouldn't it be?

What I am trying to achieve;

As it stands my view below has fixed widths and heights, I personally want it to fit the screen proportionately so fully adapt to the size of the screen but different text views do deserve different weightings I suppose which I read is linear layout, but then with linear layout I cannot understand how to get the 2x2 grid at the end of my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rv_lines"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_ID"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_ID"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_ID" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_DIFFICULTY" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/score_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_SCORE"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/questions_text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_SUMTYPE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TV_RV_OutOfText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TV_RV_QCOUNT_TEXT" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just some added info on the different text views. The first one is an integer record ID from the database. Second is a string from easy to impossible. The third is either a mathematical symbol or the word "random". Then the 2x2 fields are small text strings with a field next to them to show 0-99

Comment: You ask a big question. It sounds like you are leaning toward going with _LinearLayout_. My advice would be to stay with _ConstraintLayout_. It should work for you. For instance, regarding proportionate spacing, _ConstraintLayout_ has [weighted chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#weighted-chains) which will do what I think you want to do.

Comment: @Cheticamp I probably wasn't asking the right questions to google when researching as didn't come across weighted chains. I will get cracking on researching that link and post my results. Thank you for your response, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Cheticamp Thanks again, just to advise I have successfully created a weighted chain. Onwards and upwards :)